# Binary file reading error, Is it an endian issue or a file reading issue?

Tags: c, binary, virtual-machine, filereader

currently i am working on the starts of a simple c VM which reads in a binary file to a "memory" array and then will fetch decode and evaluate the instructions given. At the moment i am stuck in how to properly read this binary file into memory to be able to read for later use in decoding and separating it based on 2 or 4 bytes. My input is not matching what i am getting for my output which i have put below and i am unsure if this is an endian issue or if i am not reading the file into memory correctly.

**MAIN.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXMEM 1024

unsigned memory[MAXMEM];

int loads(char *filename)
{
    File *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    return fread(memory, sizeof *memory, MAXMEM, file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc <= 1){
        printf("No file Found\n");
        return -1;
        }
    char *filename = argv[1];
    loads(filename);
    printf("%04x\n", *memory);
}
```

**INPUT.BIN** (Data gotten from running `od -x --endian=big input.bin | head -5`)

```
00000000 b10a b200 1123
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
b20ab1
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
either b10a b200 1123 
or b1 0a b2 00 11 23
```

Comment: You want `sizeof(unsigned)` I think. Also your printing is weird. Actually you only print the first element which is `00 b2 0a b1` printf will not print the leading zeros so its `b20ab1`. Put another print with `memory[1]` and see what happens.

Comment: Note that the function: `fread()` returns a `size_t` not a `int`

Comment: regarding the expression: `sizeof *memory,`  This is asking for the number of bytes where `memory` points  Not a good idea, especially as `memory` is not a pointer.  suggest using: `sizeof memory`

Comment: regarding: in function: `main()` `loads(filename);`  and the signature for `loads()` is:  `int loads(char *filename)`   (which, BTW: is not correct the correct return type) the `main()` function is ignoring the information in the returned value

Comment: OT: in general, when the user has not supplied the desired command line parameters the code typically displays a `usage` statement similar to:  `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `File *file`  That first `File` should be: `FILE`  Didn't your compiler tell you about this problem?

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");`  (notice I capitalized the returned type)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "fopen failed" );` so both the enclosed error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the display problem is all in this statement:

```
printf("%04x\n", *memory);
```

first use a format string that represents the format you want displayed.   Perhaps:

```
"%02x %02x %02x $02x\n"
```

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly handles I.O errors
4. does not include header files those contents are not used

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAXMEM 1024

char memory[MAXMEM];

size_t loads(char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if( !file )
    {
        perror( "fopen for read failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    return  fread(memory, sizeof *memory, MAXMEM, file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char *filename = argv[1];
    size_t fileSize = loads(filename);
    printf( "File Size: %zu\n", fileSize );
    printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", 
           memory[0], 
           memory[1], 
           memory[2], 
           memory[3]);
}
```

when run against this same source file results in:

```
File Size: 701
23 69 6e 63
```

Note: the `23 69 6e 63` is the hex values for `#inc`

I modified the memory to have type `char`.  If you want to keep it `unsigned` then note that a 32 bit unsigned contains 8 nibbles, so the format string of the call to `printf()` should be `%08x` for each unsigned value to display